# Is it feasible to install 3000 mAh battery to MMX A89 mobile?

Tags: battery-life, micromax-a89

```
Device : MMX A89
OS : ICS 4.0.4
Battery : 1400 mAh
```

Is it feasible install 3000 mAh battery to MMX A89 mobile?

As internet is ON on mobile so it's getting drain within 6 to 8 hours and I am not using internet with lot of use. Although battery get drained so quickly.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://phone-debate.com/phones/comparison-versus/1315/1225/xolo-q900-vs-micromax-a89-ninja), your Micromax A89 Ninja phone has a removable back plate with a replaceable battery.  It should be possible to replace the original 1400 mAh battery with a higher capacity one. However such battery will definitely be thicker in size, so you would most likely need to buy a different back plate to accommodate for the added thickness (see an example for Galaxy S4 [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/350849243884).)

I have not found any online merchant that sells extended batteries for Micromax A89, but you may have better luck with local cell phone dealerships in your part of the world.